# errors handling on footer should pop up

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, sql

just as i know that is the login form and the register form is need to have the error handling
and i'm using a php for the main code language, there is such an errors handling if i put into an php language its kind of silly, i mean the design is more or less than nothing

i want to put an error handling like
"Your Username and Password Combination is Incorrect",
'We Can\'t Find That Username',
'You Need To Enter a Username And a Password',

on the footer page it will pop up message if the user is do something wrong with the form

this is my code **html**:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="header-content">
        <div id="logo"> <a href="index.php" style="text-decoration:none;">
                    logo</a>

        </div>
        <div id="searchbox">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" size="50" class="searchbox">
        </div>
```

**PHP**

```
if(empty($_POST) === false){
$username = $_POST['input-username'];
$password = $_POST['input-password'];

    if(empty($username) === true || empty($password) ===true){
        $errors[] = 'You Need To Enter a Username And a Password';
        }
        else if(user_exists($username) === false){
        $errors[] = 'We Can\'t Find That Username';
            }

        else{
            $login = login($username, $password);

                if($login === false){
                    $errors[] = 'Your Username and Password Combination is Incorrect';
                    }
                else{
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
                    header('Location: home.php');

                    }
            }

        print_r($errors);
}
```

and back to form in **html**

```
<div id="users">
    <form method="post" action="" name="signin-form">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="input-username" id="input-username">
                </td>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" name="input-password" id="input-password">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="sign-in" id="sign-in" value="Log in">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me">
                    <label id="information">Keep Me Eating Picture</label>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2"> <a href="#" id="forgotpass">Forgotten My Username or Password</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <button id="sign-up">Sign Up</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

there is some core items that i can't show in here
such as connect to database
and function page(which is the page full of function that i need)

im showing this code for information that i'm using array errors handling but i want to show the error message on footer side
somebody please help me
btw sorry for my english, and thx for your concern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to show the error on the `footer` page.

You could try something like: (which I tested with 2 small files)

**NOTE:** I could not test with brackets, but this worked.

```
$errors = include 'footer_error_message.php';
```

yet do try with brackets, it should work.

```
$errors[] = include 'footer_error_message.php';
```

Then in your `footer.php` file for example you would have something to the affect of:

```
echo "Your Username and Password Combination is Incorrect";
```

### EDIT (added popup JS message)

In your error message file, you can do the following:

You can use this as your popup error message. (in `error_incorrect_info.php` for example)

```
<?php

$errormessage = "Your Username and Password Combination is Incorrect";

echo "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">
    alert('$errormessage');

</script>
";

?>
```

#### Reformatted could look like this:

```
if(empty($_POST) === false){
$username = $_POST['input-username'];
$password = $_POST['input-password'];

    if(empty($username) === true || empty($password) ===true){
        $errors[] = include 'error_enter_info.php';
        }
        else if(user_exists($username) === false){
        $errors[] = 'We Can\'t Find That Username';
            }

        else{
            $login = login($username, $password);

                if($login === false){
                    $errors[] = include 'error_incorrect_info.php';
                    }
                else{
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
                    header('Location: home.php');

                    }
            }

        print_r($errors);
}
```

Comment: YOU GOT THIS buddy but ummm...
if i want to fill a footer with errors message should i do a Javascript code right?

the problem is i'm very new in html, css, php, and sql
but about javascript and jQuery i'm a blind man.. can u share what a good tutorial to learn javascript and jQuery?

Comment: @Obink You may also want to Google "ajax php" but that's a bit of an advanced topic, yet could prove to be fruitful down the road. :)

Comment: @Obink Have a look at my **EDIT**, I added a Javascript popup option.

Comment: thank you so much Fredd
i will do my best :D
ok i will check that js